Using regex (Geany) to remove duplicate strings
I have Geany and I assume it uses PCRE regex.  I have a list of lines that looks something like this:
Kurt Phoebe ColtKurt Phoebe Colt
Lane AnselLane Ansel
Taylor Retha EvansTaylor Retha Evans
Hilary Mitchell StephensonHilary Mitchell Stephenson
Lizzie EasonLizzie Eason
Freida DurandFreida Durand
Zelma Ibbie ThompkinsZelma Ibbie Thompkins
Felicity MarvinFelicity Marvin
Kira Norma BlackmanKira Norma Blackman
Marcia RickardMarcia Rickard

Some of the words have punctuation but each line has a duplicate string with no space separating it.
How can I use regex to find the duplicate strings?

This is not a regex problem.  If that's really the input, then just take the length of the line, divide the length by 2, and ensure the two halves are equal.

And how would I do that without using a programming language?

Since the divider word has two capitals regex could search for a word with two capital letters and using search and replace put a space in front of the second capital letter.  Then a simple duplicate word search cold be done.

The word that needs to be divided starts with the same word that's at the end of the line.  If regex could find the letters of the ending word in another word a space could be inserted and and a duplicate word search could be done.

You would use a scripting language.  The problem would be solved in a few minutes, and you could reuse the code later.  Use the right tool for the job.

If you mean, for example, that you wish to match "Kurt Phoebe Colt" in "Kurt Phoebe ColtKurt Phoebe Colt", you can do that with the regular expression ^(.+)(?=\1$).  Demo. At the link hover the cursor over each token of the regex to obtain an explanation of its function.

^(.+)\1$ --> \1

Thank you, Cary Swoveland you have the answer and it worked.  You were very helpful and you deserve the credit for finding the correct answer.  You're one of the good guys.

No PCRE. Please check https://www.geany.org/manual/gtk/glib/glib-regex-syntax.html
